# How to parse JSON data of this type to an array?

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

RE-fix the parsing code and got the following JSON. How do I proceed to create 2 separate arrays: one for prefcode and one for prefName?

JSON:

> [
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 1,
>           "prefName" : "北海道"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 2,
>           "prefName" : "青森県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 3,
>           "prefName" : "岩手県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 4,
>           "prefName" : "宮城県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 5,
>           "prefName" : "秋田県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 6,
>           "prefName" : "山形県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 7,
>           "prefName" : "福島県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 8,
>           "prefName" : "茨城県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 9,
>           "prefName" : "栃木県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 10,
>           "prefName" : "群馬県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 11,
>           "prefName" : "埼玉県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 12,
>           "prefName" : "千葉県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 13,
>           "prefName" : "東京都"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 14,
>           "prefName" : "神奈川県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 15,
>           "prefName" : "新潟県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 16,
>           "prefName" : "富山県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 17,
>           "prefName" : "石川県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 18,
>           "prefName" : "福井県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 19,
>           "prefName" : "山梨県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 20,
>           "prefName" : "長野県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 21,
>           "prefName" : "岐阜県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 22,
>           "prefName" : "静岡県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 23,
>           "prefName" : "愛知県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 24,
>           "prefName" : "三重県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 25,
>           "prefName" : "滋賀県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 26,
>           "prefName" : "京都府"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 27,
>           "prefName" : "大阪府"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 28,
>           "prefName" : "兵庫県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 29,
>           "prefName" : "奈良県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 30,
>           "prefName" : "和歌山県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 31,
>           "prefName" : "鳥取県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 32,
>           "prefName" : "島根県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 33,
>           "prefName" : "岡山県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 34,
>           "prefName" : "広島県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 35,
>           "prefName" : "山口県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 36,
>           "prefName" : "徳島県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 37,
>           "prefName" : "香川県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 38,
>           "prefName" : "愛媛県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 39,
>           "prefName" : "高知県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 40,
>           "prefName" : "福岡県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 41,
>           "prefName" : "佐賀県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 42,
>           "prefName" : "長崎県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 43,
>           "prefName" : "熊本県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 44,
>           "prefName" : "大分県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 45,
>           "prefName" : "宮崎県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 46,
>           "prefName" : "鹿児島県"
>         },
>         {
>           "prefCode" : 47,
>           "prefName" : "沖縄県"
>         }
>       ]

ViewController Code :

```
import UIKit
    import SwiftyJSON
    import Alamofire
    import Foundation

    struct Citys: Decodable {
        let prefCode: Int
        let cityName: String
        let cityCode: Int
        let bigCityFlag: Int

    }


    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var City: UILabel!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib


            if let BASEURL = URL(string: "https://opendata.resas-portal.go.jp/api/v1/prefectures?") {
                var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: BASEURL)
                urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

                var headers: HTTPHeaders
                if let existingHeaders = urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields {
                    headers = existingHeaders
                } else {
                    headers = HTTPHeaders()
                }
                headers["X-API-KEY"] = "4GMF0uUh7T9UHFvcp8xq6r4WnGnBA6arqJpuoPIS"
                //headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                headers["charset"] = "utf-8"
                urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

                let request = Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        //debugPrint(response)
                        guard let object = response.result.value else {
                            print("Error")
                            return
                        }

                        //print(response)
                        let propertyJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                        self.updateName(json: propertyJSON)

                }

            }
        }

        //MARK: - JSON Parsing
        /***************************************************************/

        func updateName(json : JSON) {

            for result in json {
                print(result.1)
            }
```

Comment: This not valid json data

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong Benny, but `result` is supposed to be an `array` of objects. If I'm right about it, then should be enclosed within `[ ]` and not `( )` and also key-value pairs need to be having a `:` not an `=`. And which part of this data do you want to be part of the array?

Comment: It was generated from calling an api. I’m interested in data in the cityCode, cityName and prefCode. Is there any way to extract the data without having to reformat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Benny, the data which you have provided as JSON data is not valid as JSON data. There are quite a few errors. i have listed them below:

- in each key-value pair, the key and value should be separated by a **colon** `:` and not `=` as you have shown. For example:  `message = "<null>"` ==> `message: "<null>"`
- successive key-value pairs should be separated by **comma**s and not `;`. For example:  `bigCityFlag = 2; cityCode = 01100;` ==> `bigCityFlag: 2, cityCode: 01100,`
- Also, `result` is supposed to be an array of objects, I presume. If I'm right about it, then it should be enclosed within `[ ]` and not `( )`, which would make it: `result: ({` ==> `result: [{`.

[Emmanuel has suggested a good way to make these changes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53920683/10232790) Assuming you have used this or some other approach to rectify it into valid JSON data, you could use the following approach to get the `result` part of it into respective arrays.

```js
var SUCCESS = {
  message: "<null>",
  result: [{
    bigCityFlag: 2,
    cityCode: 01100,
    cityName: "\U672d\U5e4c\U5e02",
    prefCode: 1
  }, {
    bigCityFlag: 1,
    cityCode: 01101,
    cityName: "\U672d\U5e4c\U5e02\U4e2d\U592e\U533a",
    prefCode: 1
  }, {
    bigCityFlag: 1,
    cityCode: 01102,
    cityName: "\U672d\U5e4c\U5e02\U5317\U533a",
    prefCode: 1
  }, {
    bigCityFlag: 1,
    cityCode: 01103,
    cityName: "\U672d\U5e4c\U5e02\U6771\U533a",
    prefCode: 1
  }, {
    bigCityFlag: 0,
    cityCode: 47382,
    cityName: "\U4e0e\U90a3\U56fd\U753a",
    prefCode: 47
  }]
};

var bigCityFlag = [];
var cityCode = [];
var cityName = [];
var prefCode = [];

for (var i = 0; i < SUCCESS.result.length; i++) {
  bigCityFlag[i] = SUCCESS.result[i].bigCityFlag;
  cityCode[i] = SUCCESS.result[i].cityCode;
  cityName[i] = SUCCESS.result[i].cityName;
  prefCode[i] = SUCCESS.result[i].prefCode;
}

console.log("BIG CITY FLAG = [ " + bigCityFlag + " ]");
console.log("CITY CODE = [ " + cityCode + " ]");
console.log("CITY NAME = [ " + cityName + " ]");
console.log("PREF CODE = [ " + prefCode + " ]");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Json Data, and I wouldn't recommend using this approach. But if you had to you could parse it using regex and string replacements as follows. Considering that the $DATA variable contains what you posted above.

```
// Replace the following characters: ( ) = ; with these: [ ] : ,
// and escape backslashes, \ becomes \\ (also must be escaped for the str_replace call)
$DATA = str_replace(['(',')', '=', ';', '\\'], ['[',']',':', ',', '\\\\'], $DATA);

// Remove SUCCESS: from the start
$DATA = trim($DATA, 'SUCCESS:');

// Wrap keys with quotes ""
$DATA = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s\:/', '"$1":', $DATA);

// Trim zeros from integer values
$DATA = preg_replace('/:\s[0]+[1-9]/', ': ', $DATA);

// Remove comma from last item in array
$DATA = preg_replace('/,([\r|\n|\s]+)([\[|\}|\)])/', '$1$2', $DATA);

// Decode Json
$JSON = json_decode($DATA);

// Voila!
print_r($JSON);
```

Comment: This is written in PHP, but could be as easily written in Javascript